# Finding contiguous number ranges of local category groups

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, gaps-and-islands

I am new to Power Query (M Language). I understand the basics of Power Query but I have come across a use case with special grouping requirements.

Suppose my source data is like:

| Invoice# | Customer# |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | A |
| 3 | B |
| 4 | A |
| 5 | A |
| 6 | B |
| 7 | B |

And I would like it to be transformed to:

| From Invoice# | To Invoice# | Customer# |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | A |
| 3 | 3 | B |
| 4 | 5 | A |
| 6 | 7 | B |

I understand it is a kind of "gaps and islands" problem and I know how to do it in SQL. However I'm not sure if Power Query (M) is able to handle this type of transform.

How can I achieve this result?

Answer (score 1):

This is straightforward in Power Query using a special optional keyword to set the grouping kind: `GroupKind.Local`. The table has to be sorted correctly by invoice number for this to work. See example code you can paste into a blank query:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMlTSUXJUitWJVjKCs4yBLCcwywQuZgpnmcFlzSGsWAA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"Invoice#" = _t, #"Customer#" = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Invoice#", Int64.Type}, {"Customer#", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Customer#"}, {{"Invoice From", each List.Min([#"Invoice#"]), type nullable number}, {"Invoice To", each List.Max([#"Invoice#"]), type nullable number}}, GroupKind.Local)
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Great, it always seems worth looking for hidden options!